# To make a character array that contains double data type numbers

Tags: c

I want to make a character array of double data type numbers. For example:
an array like this:

```
unsigned char ABC[6]={'2.3','5.7','5.66'}
```

The problem is that the array does take `ABC[0]=2.3`, instead it takes `2` only. How can I fix it?

Comment: `2.3` is 3 characters

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const char *ABC[] = { "2.3", "5.7", "5.66" };
```

and then you can just treat each element of `ABC` as a string, e.g.:

```
printf("%s\n", ABC[0]);
```

will print:

```
2.3
```

Comment: No my problem is not to print. Instead I need to send this array as it is in to the controller

Comment: Sure - the `printf` is just an example - you can do whatever you like with `ABC[0]` (and other indices of `ABC[]`), including sending it to your controller or whatever else you need to do.